# get String from nested Map in dart

Tags: json, dart, flutter, decode

My Map:

```
{Info: {name: Austin, Username: austinr}}
```

I'm using this line to get the myName variable to be set as "Austin"

```
String myName = map["name"] as String;
```

However.. this line seems to set the string "myName" to null.
just looking for a way to extract my name and Username from the map

Thanks

Comment: Is the map a json Object?

Comment: I could use jsonEncode to make it one, correct?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I am able to run the following code successfully.

```
 var map =  {"Info":{"name": "Austin", "Username": "austinr"}}; 
 String myString = map["Info"]["name"] as String;
 print(myString);
```

The output is `Austin` as expected. Please try this.

Comment: That is what I was looking for, Thanks

Answer (score 4):

Also if you want to work with maps in Dart, especially with nested keys, you can use [gato](https://pub.dev/packages/gato) package too.

**Basic way:**

```dart
var map = {
  'Info': {
    'name': 'Austin',
    'Username': 'austinr',
    'address': {'city': 'New York'}
  }
};

String city = map['Info']['address']['city'] as String;
print(city);
```

But it's a little dirty and also you will get an error if there wasn't the `address` key in your map.

**Using [Gato](https://pub.dev/packages/gato)**

```dart
import 'package:gato/gato.dart' as gato;
.
.
.

var map = {
  'info': {
    'name': 'Austin',
    'username': 'austinr',
    'address': {'city': 'New York'}
  }
};

// Get value from a map
print(gato.get<String>(map, 'info.address.city')); // New York

// Set a value to a map
map = gato.set<String>(map, 'info.address.city', 'Other City');

print(gato.get<String>(map, 'info.address.city')); // Other City
```

[Full document](https://pub.dev/packages/gato)

Comment: Running the gato code provided by you is giving me the following error

```
New York
Unhandled exception:
type '_InternalLinkedHashMap<String, dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'Map<String, Map<String, Object>>'
#0      main (package:flood_mobile/Playground/test_create_file_folder_structure.dart:30:5)
#1      _delayEntrypointInvocation.<anonymous closure> (dart:isolate-patch/isolate_patch.dart:283:19)
#2      _RawReceivePortImpl._handleMessage (dart:isolate-patch/isolate_patch.dart:184:12)
```

Comment: This problem has been solved, please use the latest version of `Gato` package.